# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer este array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

¿Cómo puedo recorrer este tipo de array???

El problema es que tengo una function que me retorna un `array = []` creado a partir de una respuesta json de jQuery. luego de conversion a un `array[]`, no puedo acceder a los elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola KeyWords, bienvenido a [es.so]. Debido a que no todos tenemos acceso a las imágenes, es preferible que agregues código a tu pregunta. Mucho mejor si es un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender el error. Usa este enlace __[edit]__.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo una rutina general que te permite recorrer un objeto independientemente de su estructura.

Ejemplo:

```js
array=[ {
 item1:"value1",
 item2:{
  item1:"value1",
  item2:"value2",
  item3:{
   item1:"value1",
   item2:"value2",
   item3:"value3",
   item4:{
    item1:"value1",
    item2:"value2",
    item3:"value3",
    item4:"value4",
    item5:"value5"
   }
  }
 }
}]

// funcion para Recorer el Array, (parent = nombre del objeto padre)
function search(array,parent) {

// iterar en cada elemento del Array:
 for (child in array) {

  // Si el Elemento es un Objeto:
  if (typeof array[child] == "object") {

   // Entonces invoco la función search(..) para recorrer el Objeto
   // Paso como parámetros el Objeto y Nombre del Elemento (parent):
   search(array[child],parent+child+".");
  } else {

   // De no ser un Objeto imprime:
   // El nombre del Elemento al cual podemos acceder:
   console.log(parent+child+":");

   // y el Valor del Elemento:
   console.log(array[child]);
  };
 };
};
search(array[0],"");
```

Una vez conocido los elementos que componen el objeto quedara de tu parte que hacer con ellos.

En el siguiente ejemplo intentare recrear un **json** como el que planteas en tu imagen, luego recorreremos el objeto creando un `<select>` y un `<table>`

Ejemplo:

```js
array = [
  {
    "0": {
      "id": "1",
      "nombre": "PRIMERO"
    },
    "1": {
      "id": "2",
      "nombre": "SEGUNDO"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "3",
      "nombre": "TERCERO"
    },
    "3": {
      "id": "4",
      "nombre": "CUARTO"
    },
    "4": {
      "id": "5",
      "nombre": "QUINTO"
    },
    "5": {
      "id": "6",
      "nombre": "SEXTO"
    },
    "6": {
      "id": "7",
      "nombre": "SEPTIMO"
    },
    "7": {
      "id": "8",
      "nombre": "OCTAVO"
    },
    "8": {
      "id": "9",
      "nombre": "NOVENO"
    },
    "9": {
      "id": "10",
      "nombre": "DECIMO"
    },
    "10": {
      "id": "11",
      "nombre": "DECIMO PRIMERO"
    }
  }
];

// Obtiene el Objeto que esta dentro del Array (elemento 0)
obj = array[0];

// Crea el elemento html <select>
select = document.createElement("select");

// recorre obj
for(i in obj) {

 // Crea el elemento html <option>
 option = document.createElement("option");

 // Asigna el valor del elemento <option value="..">
 option.value = obj[i].id;

 // Asigna el texto del elemento <option>texto<option>
 option.text  = obj[i].nombre;

 // Añade el elemento <option> al <select>
 select.appendChild(option);
};

// Añade el elemento <select> al <body> de la pagina
document.body.appendChild(select);


// Crea el elemento html <table>
table = document.createElement("table");

// recorre obj
for(i in obj) {

 // Crea el elemento html <tr>
 tr = document.createElement("tr");

 // Asigna el valor id <td>id.. </td> a <tr>
 td = document.createElement("td");
 td.innerHTML=obj[i].id;
 tr.appendChild(td);

 // Asigna el valor nombre <td>nombre.. </td> a <tr>
 td = document.createElement("td");
 td.innerHTML=obj[i].nombre;
 tr.appendChild(td);

 // Añade el elemento <tr> a <table>
 table.appendChild(tr);
};

// Añade el elemento <table> al <body> de la pagina
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid ;
}
```

Espero esto te sirve, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: No entiendo la funcion disculpa, que valor es pf? y como esta funcion retorna los valores, Lo que requiero es recuperar los valores para luego hacer algo asi en jquery $html = "<option value='"+ data.id +"'>"+ data.nombre+"</option>"; obvio dentro de un $.each o for. que valla recorriendolo.

Comment: esta función te permite conocer cada propiedad (o elemento) que compone un objeto, conociendo esto podrás acceder a cualquiera de sus elementos., creo que esa es tu pregunta "**..no puedo acceder a los elementos..**" lo que quiere decir que desconoces como esta compuesto el objeto puesto que de otra forma podrías acceder a ellos.

Comment: por cierto `pf` es el nombre del objeto padre. tienes una Array donde hay un solo elemento, y ese elemento a su vez se compone de objetos que a su ves tiene mas objetos, es por ello que con la función que te deje podrás recorrer esa estructura e ir conociendo los elementos que la componen.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y agradezco tu tiempo, ya la prove y la funcion no logra retornarme nada. Al colocar el console.log(data) que es la returna el arrayObjetcs de mi json jquery, me muestra lo de la imagen, asi coloque tu funcion y al mandar la peticion sigue sin responder. pero te agradezco.

Comment: Amigo, la rutina es capaz de recorrer cualquier objeto, he modificado mi respuesta comentando cada paso, si puedes copiar el objeto en https://jsfiddle.net/ podría analizarlo y tratar de entender que no puedes leer del objeto, te parece?

Comment: Ok, lo que intento crear es una funcion dinamica, que me retorne la informacion para yo manipularla y colocarla en el DOM (select, table, etc). la respuesta del servidor siempre es echo json_encode($Datos). Aqui esta lo que he hecho hasta el momento. https://jsfiddle.net/Lq3kkjzz/1/

Comment: Lo que quiere es el objeto, puedes hacer lo siguiente para https://jsfiddle.net/guLq4f6w/ de esta forma podre hacer pruebas.

Comment: No comprendo tu respuesta. Lo que requiere es retornar el objeto para luego manipularlo, en un each o for, que permite crear los n option de un select o tr td de una tabla, con sus respectivos valor. EJe:
$.each(json, function(key, value){ html.append("<option value='"+ value.id+"'>"+ value.nombre+"</option>")})

Comment: Yo creo que tu último comentario es prácticamente tu respuesta, únicamente que es un objeto de objetos, deberías recorrerlo con: $.each(array[0], function (i, obj) { console.log(obj.id, obj.nombre); });

Answer (score 0):

En realidad lo que tienes ahí es un array de un único elemento.

Este elemento es un objeto donde si tienes los diferentes elementos por los que intentas iterar:

```js
// Este es el array que tienes en realidad
var foo = [{0: {id: '1', nombre: 'PRIMERO'}, 1: {id: '2', nombre: 'SEGUNDO'}, 2: {id: '3', nombre: 'TERCERO'}, 3: {id: '4', nombre: 'CUARTO'}, 4: {id: '5', nombre: 'QUINTO'}, 5: {id: '6', nombre: 'SEXTO'}, 6: {id: '7', nombre: 'SEPTIMO'}, 7: {id: '8', nombre: 'OCTAVO'}, 8: {id: '9', nombre: 'NOVENO'}, 9: {id: '10', nombre: 'DECIMO'}, 10: {id: '11', nombre: 'DECIMOPRIMERO'} }];

//console.log(foo);

// Para recorrerlo:
for (var i in foo[0]){
  console.log('id: ' + foo[0][i].id + ', nombre: ' + foo[0][i].nombre + '\n');
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero ya eso lo he intentado y no logro acceder a los elementos. he realizado hasta dos loops uno dentro de otro y tampoco. Creo que he intenado de muchas formas acceder a los niveles internos.

Comment: En el ejemplo te muestro cómo recorrerlo. Para ver cual es el problema de tu código habría que verlo.